# Increase query performance where large number of values appear in primary key

Tags: sql-server, optimization, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I have a query where there are numerous values passed in

This is a heavily simplified version of the query

```
SELECT Id, Name, <other cols..>
FROM Table
<various joins etc.>
WHERE Id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7....1000,1001,1002 etc.)
```

I have noticed that when passing in fewer values the query is quick and uses the required index to return the data, however after a certain amount of values the query uses a constant scan and a hash table to join to the main result set which is killing the performance.

Is there a better way of returning this data?

Comment: I suggest you read [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/09/sql-plan/rewriting-queries-improve-performance).

Comment: Seeks escalate to scans when the optimizer thinks it's cheaper. For large numbers of seek values, it often *is* cheaper to scan. You can force a seek if you want to test it: `FROM Table WITH(FORCESEEK)`.

Comment: What is the definition of "table"? What is the definition of the index? What is a query plan for a fast query? What is a query plan for a slow query? How long do the queries take to finish? What is your target response time? You can use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Answer (score 1):

Put your values into #tmp table and join it with the rest of your query

Comment: Can you explain why your suggestion could help with performance?